# User Picture on Dashboard

Tags: dashboard

When the report on owner, the owner picture will show on dashboard; however if it's assigned to (still a user), only name shows on dashboard.  How can we show the user picture for "assigned to" column/field?

Comment: "Show Chatter Photos" is already checked for the tabular data / report.